# share opencart login sessions across muti stores in sub domains

Tags: php, session, opencart

I have a opencart site with muti store installed. There are around 4 stores installed in sub domains using the multi store feature

```
mystore.com
a.mystore.com
b.mystore.com
c.mystore.com
```

the problem is when a user logins to any store and if he is moving to a different store, the user needs to login again. I find this annoying for users.

Is there a way to share the login session across all the subdoamins so when a users logins to any store he will be logged to all the other stores automatically?

I need only share only the login, not the cart.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this type of structure, You need to work as API structure. Follow steps,

1) Create one token on login and store this token over session/memcache server

2) Store this token in your cookie

3) Pass this token on every call of your domain. Fetch from cookie and pass to your website

4) Your website will identify this token with your session server. If found then it's logged in

Hope that helps !!!

Comment: And the cookie has to be set for `*.mystore.com` so that it is transparent also on each sub-domain.

Answer (score 1):

Easy Solution,

1. OPEN FILE: system/library/session.php
2. FIND LINE: session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
3. APPEND   : session_set_cookie_params(0, '/','**.DOMAIN.COM**);

Make sure to include the period **"."** before DOMAIN.COM

That's it...  Now login sessions started on **www.domain.com** is shared with **www.sub.domain.com**

Note, this will share BOTH Login and Cart